# JavaScript why is array.filter skipping first value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found a strange quirk with `array.filter` that I haven't found any reference to yet. I was trying to get the first three values in an array using a conditional set to return all values with an index less than 3. But the resulting array does not contain the first value. I took out my conditional to compare it to `.map` and `.forEach`, and those two methods retrieve the first value. Am I missing something about `.filter`?

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var filterArr = arr.filter(function(v,i){ return v; });

console.log(filterArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

var mapArr = arr.map(function(v,i){ return v; });

console.log(mapArr); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
 
var eachArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(v,i){
 eachArr.push(v);
});

console.log(eachArr); [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: ...because you did not read the documentation of `Array.prototype.filter()`

Answer (score 3):

The [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) calls a callback for each element, where the callback is a:

> Function to test each element of the array. Invoked with arguments (element, index, array). Return true to keep the element, **false** otherwise.

You're returning `v`, the element passed to it.  `0` is "[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)", so the resulting filtered array doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 1):

You're filtering out the first value:

```
var filterArr = arr.filter(function(v,i){ return v; });
```

`filter` runs through each element and removes an item if it returns `false`. `0` equates to `false` in a boolean context. That's why the first element is gone.